# Logo on Facebook looks blurry?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a confusing issue, I delivered the logo to the client with the standard sizes for social media applications (link to the page I took sizes from https://globalspex.com/logo-dimensions/ ), but he came back and told me that FB size which is 200px*200px looks blurry. I tried it myself and it looked blurry too. Now my question is: are those sizes in this link(In other links too all over the internet) wrong, or there is something that I don't understand?. And if they are correct then why the logo looks blurry? (it looks blurry on all social media sizes). should I only deliver 5000px*5000px version instead of these sizes? (because I tried it and it's very good on all social media apps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "standard sizes" for social media applications. Each application has its own sizes.

1. Please google the sizes and look for each answer each social media has.

https://www.facebook.com/help/125379114252045

2. Another simple thing to do is, go to Facebook and take a measure of the images.

I would trust more this second option. The images it seems are not resampled to 170 px as the facebook page says. They seem to be at 180 px.

But as all on the internet. You can not control it. So make your logo as everyone else and focus on more important things.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the file formate here. Why not check with the PNG. In my experience, I've used several sizes 200, 300, 500, 180 and so many, no matter how big the source file.  Also, You did not mention anything about the tool used to create a profile image. If you use **Photoshop** then Select the Color Profile **sRGB**

[image]

Comment: I used adobe illustrator to create my logo, and what do you mean by( Why not check with the PNG. In my experience, I've used several sizes 200, 300, 500, 180 and so many, no matter how big the source file) ? @clippingpath